# I need to list out the Custom list and library from SharePoint Site?

Tags: list, web-parts, sharepoint-2010

I need to list out the Custom list and library from SharePoint Site?
How to identify the content is comes under the custom created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code should help you

```
            SPList myList=SPContext.Current.Web.Lists["YourList"];
            if (myList.BaseType == SPBaseType.DocumentLibrary)
            {
                //My List is Document Library
            }

            if (myList.BaseType == SPBaseType.GenericList)
            {
                //My List is Custom List
            }
```

Comment: i tried to get the current web using client object model.i am not able to get that..please guide me to find it
ClientContext context = new ClientContext(ApplicationContext.Current.Url);

ithis is available in net.. but its not working

Answer (score 2):

This code will help you

```
     using (SPWeb web = currentSite.OpenWeb())
        {
            foreach (SPList list in web.Lists)
            {
                if (list.BaseType == SPBaseType.DocumentLibrary
                   &&
                list.BaseTemplate == SPListTemplateType.DocumentLibrary
                )
                {
               ListItem li = new ListItem();
                li.Text = list.Title;
                li.Value = list.ID.ToString();

                 }
                else if(list.BaseType == SPBaseType.GenericList
                    &&
                    list.BaseTemplate == SPListTemplateType.GenericList)
                {
                    ListItem li = new ListItem();
                    li.Text = list.Title;
                    li.Value = list.ID.ToString();

                }
            }
          }
```